# HTML ordered lists - skipping numbers?

Tags: html, css, list

My college project is to create a web page, with 3 tiers, multimedia and a site map.
Sounds simple enough, but I can't find the section of code that is causing my ordered list to skip numbers 2 and 3.

I've been pulling my hair out for 2 days now, and I decided to submit my query online and see if a pro can spot the issue.

I have just created the top tier so far, and adding content and multimedia (not researched) just to see how it looks.

I've been using W3Schools http://www.w3schools.com/html/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml_lists_ordered and when the list is isolated it works fine, but when added to the page it starts to skip numbers.

Could someone help me out?

```css
.col-2-3 {
    width: 66.66%;
}

.col-1-3 {
    width: 33.33%;
}

h1 {
    color: green;
    background: blue;
    border: 1px dashed black;
    padding: 2px;
    width: 1305px;
}

h2 {
    font-style: italic;
    text-shadow: 3px 2px #000;
    color: #ff0;
    font-size: 36px;
}

li {
    padding-left: 140px
}

p {
    font-size: 20px
}

video {
    float: right;
    Margin-right: 5px;
    border-right: 5px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>

<html Lang="en">
<div class="grid">
  <div class="col-2-3">
  </div>
  <div class="col-1-3">
  </div>
</div>
<html>
<head>

  <title>Siberian Huskies</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">

  <style>
    body {
      background-color: #b0c4de;
    }

    ul {
      list-style-type: none;
      margin: 0;
      padding: 0;
      overflow: hidden;
    }

    li {
      float: left;
    }

    a {
      display: block;
      width: 60px;
      background-color: #b0c4de;
    }
  </style>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="Description"
        content="All you will ever need to know about Siberian Huskies, Raw feeding
            Training, Activities"
  <meta name="keywords"
        content="siberian,huskies,husky,feeding,training,exercise,grooming,breed, breed standard,
            cross breeding,undercoat,vaccine,immunisation"
</head>

<body>
  <h1><img src="smbanner.png" alt="Snowy mountain" height="150" width="1300"></h1>
  <ul>
    <li><a href="Siberian Huskies.HTML">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="Training.HTML">Training</a></li>
    <li><a href="Exercise.HTML">Exercise</a></li>
    <li><a href="Mushing.HTML">Mushing</a></li>
    <li><a href="FAQs.HTML">FAQs</a></li>
    <li><a href="About the Author.HTML">About</a></li>
  </ul>

  <h2> Siberian Huskies</h2>

  <p> Siberian Huskies are known the world over as hard working sled dogs. But the REAL truth is there is only one true
      "Husky" breed. We have all heard of the
      American Husky, which according to some breeders is not true husky but rather a mix of cold resistant dogs, with
      traits of low body mass and strong pulling
      instincts. The American Husky is a recognised breed (American Kennel Club) but the breed standard can vary wildly
      depending on which mix of animals is used
      to create the breed.</p>

  <p> The Siberian Husky is considered a "Pure Bred" which means it's blood line has not been diluted by other breeds, and
      is only coupled with other Siberian Huskies.
      The requirement to declare any dog a "Pure Bred" is regulated by the governing countries Kennel Club, for example if
      a person in Republic of Ireland
      wanted to breed two 'sibes' as pure bred, they first must comply with the IKC (Irish Kennel Club) and register their
      dogs with them, to do this they must first
      provide the following.

  <ol>
    <li>Parentage Certificate</li>
    <li>Pedigree certificate</li>
    <li>Life long breeder registration</li>
    <li>Submit a signed copy of the Kennel Clubs rules</li>
    <li>Provide hip,eye&ear scores</li>
    <li>The animal in question must meet the breed
        standard(http://www.thekennelclub.org.uk/services/public/breed/standard.aspx?id=5141
    </li>
    <li>Every litter planned or otherwise must be declared to the IKC and registered accordingly with microchip and
        Parentage documentation
    </li>
  </ol>
  <p>

    <video width="360" controls>

      <source src="Dogmush.mp4" type="video/mp4">
      <source src="Dogmush.ogg" type="video/ogg">
      Your browser does not support HTML5 video."
    </video>

  <p>
    Watch this video on:<a href="https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vGACUR6poPc" target="_blank">YouTube</a>.
  </p>

  <p> This is where the dogs the dogs the dogs the dogs the dogs the dogs the dogs the dogs the dogs the dogs the dogs the
      dogs the dogs the dogs
      the dogs the dogs the dogs the dogs the dogs the dogs the dogs the dogs the dogs the dogs the dogs the dogs the dogs
      the dogs the dogs the dogs
      the dogs the dogs the dogs the dogs the dogs the dogs the dogs the dogs the dogs the dogs the dogs the dogs the dogs
      the dogs the dogs the dogs </p>

  </body>

</html>
```

Comment: Just as a side note, you'd maybe ought to change your title to something more descriptive than "College project" to help people understand what the specific problem you're having is.

Comment: The question isn't very well presented, and you should include only relevant code. But still I will point you in the right direction, you are missing the numbers on you list because `<li>` is floating left so the numbers are hiding behind the `<li>` infront. Look into using classes and id's.

Comment: could you point where the problem is on your code and put your code on jsfiddle. Le ordered list works fine for me.

Comment: Yes, thanks for the pointer, I apologize  for the poorly presented question, as you may be able to tell, I am a novice and I was not sure about how to ask the question.

Comment: Please don't add "solved" to a question title.  If someone has solved your question, mark it as accepted - this way, the system can also identify it as "solved".

Answer (score 1):

It's this CSS:

```
li {float: left;}
```

Your numbers are present on the page but they are hidden under/in the text of other list items.  Remove the `float:left` and it should look correct.

Comment: Yes, that has solved the problem, thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

You have `float: left` on your li. Remove it or change it to `text-align:left`.
Don't forget to close your `<p>` tags!

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
li {
    float: left;
}
```

to this

```
ul li {
    float: left;
}
```

That way, the `float` only applies to your navigation, but not the ordered list. **Note:** As a long term solution, take a look at element IDs and classes.

Comment: Thanks Felix, I'm having a go at the <ul id="menu"> route mentioned below, your fix was exactly what I was looking for, but as usual questions lead to more complicated answers :)

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that you only apply style to the specific element you want. In your project you `float:left` all `li` elements. You can use the selector `ul li { float: left}` to solve your problem in this case.

```css
.col-2-3 {
  width: 66.66%;
}
.col-1-3 {
  width: 33.33%;
}

h1
{

 color : green ;
 background : blue ;
 border : 1px dashed black ;
 padding : 2px ;
 width : 1305px ;
 
}
h2 {
 font-style: italic;
    text-shadow: 3px 2px #000;
 color: #ff0;
 font-size:36px;
 }
 
ul li 
{
 padding-left:140px
}

p
{
 font-size:20px
}
 
video 
{
 float: right; 
 Margin-right: 5px;
 border-right: 5px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>

<html Lang="en">
<div class="grid">
  <div class="col-2-3">
  </div>
  <div class="col-1-3">
  </div>
</div>
<html>
<head>
 
 <title>Siberian Huskies</title>
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
 
 <style>
 body {
    background-color: #b0c4de;
 }
 
ul {
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
 }

li {
    float: left;
 }

a {
    display: block;
    width: 60px;
    background-color: #b0c4de;
 }
</style>
 <meta charset="UTF-8">
 <meta name="Description"
  content="All you will ever need to know about Siberian Huskies, Raw feeding
    Training, Activities"
 <meta name ="keywords"
  content="siberian,huskies,husky,feeding,training,exercise,grooming,breed, breed standard,
    cross breeding,undercoat,vaccine,immunisation"
</head>
 
 <body>
 <h1><img src="smbanner.png" alt="Snowy mountain" height="150" width="1300"> </h1>
 <ul>
  <li><a href="Siberian Huskies.HTML">Home</a></li>
  <li><a href="Training.HTML">Training</a></li>
  <li><a href="Exercise.HTML">Exercise</a></li>
  <li><a href="Mushing.HTML">Mushing</a></li>
  <li><a href="FAQs.HTML">FAQs</a></li>
  <li><a href="About the Author.HTML">About</a></li>
</ul>
 
 <h2> Siberian Huskies</h2>
 <p> Siberian Huskies are known the world over as hard working sled dogs. But the REAL truth is there is only one true "Husky" breed. We have all heard of the
  American Husky, which according to some breeders is not true husky but rather a mix of cold resistant dogs, with traits of low body mass and strong pulling
  instincts. The American Husky is a recognised breed (American Kennel Club) but the breed standard can vary wildly depending on which mix of animals is used
  to create the breed.</p>
 <p> The Siberian Husky is considered a "Pure Bred" which means it's blood line has not been diluted by other breeds, and is only coupled with other Siberian Huskies.
  The requirement to declare any dog a "Pure Bred" is regulated by the governing countries Kennel Club, for example if a person in Republic of Ireland
  wanted to breed two 'sibes' as pure bred, they first must comply with the IKC (Irish Kennel Club) and register their dogs with them, to do this they must first 
  provide the following. 
  
 <ol>
  <li>Parentage Certificate </li>
  <li>Pedigree certificate </li>
  <li>Life long breeder registration </li>
  <li>Submit a signed copy of the Kennel Clubs rules </li>
  <li>Provide hip,eye&ear scores </li>
  <li>The animal in question must meet the breed standard(http://www.thekennelclub.org.uk/services/public/breed/standard.aspx?id=5141 </li>
  <li>Every litter planned or otherwise must be declared to the IKC and registered accordingly with microchip and Parentage documentation </li>
 </ol>
 <p>
  
<video width="360" controls>
 
  <source src="Dogmush.mp4" type="video/mp4">
  <source src="Dogmush.ogg" type="video/ogg">
  Your browser does not support HTML5 video." 
</video>

<p>
Watch this video on:<a href="https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vGACUR6poPc" target="_blank">YouTube</a>.
</p>
  
 <p> This is where the dogs the dogs the dogs the dogs the dogs the dogs the dogs the dogs the dogs the dogs the dogs the dogs the dogs the dogs
  the dogs the dogs the dogs the dogs the dogs the dogs the dogs the dogs the dogs the dogs the dogs the dogs the dogs the dogs the dogs the dogs 
  the dogs the dogs the dogs the dogs the dogs the dogs the dogs the dogs the dogs the dogs the dogs the dogs the dogs the dogs the dogs the dogs </p>
 
 </body>

</html>
```

A better approach is to add id to your menu so that the style will only affect the menu `li`:

```
<ul id="menu">
    <li><a href="">Menu Item</li>
    ...
</ul>
```

And in the CSS:

```
ul#menu li {
    float: left;
}
```

Comment: That's an interesting idea, I've not heard of that until just now, I'll give a go. Cheers

Answer (score 0):

Your missing `</p>` after the sentence...

"The requirement to declare any dog a "Pure Bred" is regulated by the governing countries Kennel Club, for example if a person in Republic of Ireland wanted to breed two 'sibes' as pure bred, they first must comply with the IKC (Irish Kennel Club) and register their dogs with them, to do this they must first provide the following. [INSERT < / p > here]

and after the sentence...

Your browser does not support HTML5 video."  [INSERT < / p > here]

Comment: ok, thanks for error correction, this is a really nice site, and the people are very helpful. Thanks